# In app map navigation with voice in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, dictionary, voice, direction

I need to implement a map navigation in an iOS app to guide user from current location to the target destination. I do not want to redirect the user to another app such as Apple Map or Google Map. I need to do this inside my app. MKDirectionsRequest return step by step direction but no voice.

Also [mtdirectionsk](http://mtdirectionsk.it) has done this but I am not sure if it has the voice guide.

As far as I know this is already done in at least one app: [Uber Driver](http://9to5mac.com/2014/08/13/uber-adds-destination-entry-turn-by-turn-navigation-for-drivers-to-mobile-apps/)

Comment: did you found any way to implement it